# Entity Framework, execution order and changeset

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have the following entity:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
        List<MyEntity> _Items = new List<MyEntity>();

        [Key]
        public int MyEntityId { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }

        [Include, Composition, Association("MyEntity_MyEntity", "MyEntityId", "ParentId")]
        public List<MyEntity> Items
        {
            get { return _Items; }
            set { _Items = value; }
        }
}
```

When I delete an item of a list of this entities and then add the same entity to it, I get an error about duplicated records in DB.

I have overridden the `Submit` method like this:

```
public override bool Submit(ChangeSet changeSet)
{
            var submit1 = false;

            if (changeSet.ChangeSetEntries.Any(item => item.Operation == DomainOperation.Delete))
            {
                var deletedList = new ChangeSet(changeSet.ChangeSetEntries.Where(item => item.Operation == DomainOperation.Delete));
                submit1 = base.Submit(deletedList);
            }

            var submit2 = false;
            if (changeSet.ChangeSetEntries.Any(item => item.Operation == DomainOperation.Insert))
            {
                var insertedList = new ChangeSet(changeSet.ChangeSetEntries.Where(item => item.Operation == DomainOperation.Insert));
                submit2 = base.Submit(insertedList);
            }

            var submit3 = false;
            if (changeSet.ChangeSetEntries.Any(item => item.Operation == DomainOperation.Update))
            {
                var updatedList = new ChangeSet(changeSet.ChangeSetEntries.Where(item => item.Operation == DomainOperation.Update));
                submit3 = base.Submit(updatedList);
            }

            return submit1 && submit2 && submit3;
}
```

But now, when it tries to get the list of inserted I get the following error:

> Invalid ChangeSet : Id must be unique for each entry

Could you tell me why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have a list of itself inside the entity?

Comment: Because I need a tree structure.

Comment: If you want to nest them, you should drop the property and backing field and just declare it `public virtual ICollection<MyEntity> Items { get; set;}`, EF will take care of setting up the foreign key.

Comment: Are you saying that I should replace the line **public List<MyEntity> Items ** with **public virtual ICollection<MyEntity> Items**?
Then, I have another problem in DomainContext, if I add an entity child inside the parent entity then the property change of DomainContext doesn't fire.
Do you think this could solve it, too?
I'm working with DataBase First.